# First JSF application can't seem to navigate to first page

Tags: jsf-2, portlet, websphere-portal

I am attempting to get my first JSF page up and running on a local instance of a was server.  I can't seem to navigate to my first page. I think I have everything set up correctly, except I never get to my page.

I always get a

> "the website cannot display page"

exception.  When I look in the console to see what exceptions might have been thrown, the following are displayed:

> E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[GenericServletWrapper]: javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NullPointerException

and

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at java.util.Collections.list(Collections.java:2229)

both of those exceptions are followed by stack trace entries with no real meaning to me.  Those appear to be the most relevant entries.

Here's the entire stacktrace:

```
[12/28/12 8:16:47:719 EST] 00001b27 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[GenericServletWrapper]: javax.portlet.PortletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:369)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:82)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(PortletServletCollaborator.java:143)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doDispatch(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:60)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doDispatch(CacheCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.dispatch(PortletServlet.java:208)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.service(PortletServlet.java:165)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:548)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.invoke(PortletInvokerImpl.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerCacheCollaborator.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:313)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:101)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.invokePMI(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doInvoke(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.doRender(PortletInvokerPerformanceCollaborator.java:74)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletInvokerImpl.render(PortletInvokerImpl.java:97)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.doRender(PortletContainerImpl.java:121)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.ext.ExtCollaborator.doRender(ExtCollaborator.java:76)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheInvokerCollaborator.doRender(CacheInvokerCollaborator.java:66)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletContainerInvokerCollaboratorChainImpl.java:67)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.PortletContainerImpl.renderPortlet(PortletContainerImpl.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl$2.run(PortletInvokerImpl.java:100)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:254)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.pcinvoker.PortletInvokerImpl.invokeRender(PortletInvokerImpl.java:96)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portletserving.PortletServingServlet.invokePortletRender(PortletServingServlet.java:280)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portletserving.PortletServingServlet.service(PortletServingServlet.java:151)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1214)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portletserving.filter.PortletDocumentFilterContainer.doFilterEnd(PortletDocumentFilterContainer.java:61)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portletserving.filter.PortletDocumentFilterChain.doFilter(PortletDocumentFilterChain.java:55)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portletserving.filter.DefaultFilter.doFilter(DefaultFilter.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portletserving.filter.PortletDocumentFilterChain.doFilter(PortletDocumentFilterChain.java:49)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.portletserving.filter.PortletDocumentFilterContainer.doFilter(PortletDocumentFilterContainer.java:52)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:926)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1023)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1659)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Collections.list(Collections.java:2229)
    at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap$AbstractAttributeIterator.<init>(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:208)
    at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap$AbstractAttributeIterator.<init>(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:200)
    at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap$KeyIterator.<init>(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:233)
    at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap$KeyIterator.<init>(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:233)
    at org.apache.myfaces.util.AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap$KeySet.iterator(AbstractThreadSafeAttributeMap.java:183)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash.SubKeyMap._gatherKeys(SubKeyMap.java:121)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash.SubKeyMap.access$000(SubKeyMap.java:44)
    at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.context.flash.SubKeyMap$Entries.iterator(SubKeyMap.java:146)
    at java.util.AbstractMap$1$1.<init>(AbstractMap.java:475)
    at java.util.AbstractMap$1.iterator(AbstractMap.java:474)
    at com.ibm.faces.trace.TracePhaseListener.getMapDump(TracePhaseListener.java:305)
    at com.ibm.faces.trace.TracePhaseListener.getMapDump(TracePhaseListener.java:324)
    at com.ibm.faces.trace.TracePhaseListener.getScopeDump(TracePhaseListener.java:379)
    at com.ibm.faces.trace.TracePhaseListener.getPhaseDump(TracePhaseListener.java:291)
    at com.ibm.faces.trace.TracePhaseListener.beforePhase(TracePhaseListener.java:76)
    at com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet.restoreView(FacesPortlet.java:1429)
    at com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet.doRender(FacesPortlet.java:480)
    at com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet.doView(FacesPortlet.java:540)
    at com.ibm.faces20.portlet.FacesPortlet.doDispatch(FacesPortlet.java:412)
    at javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.render(GenericPortlet.java:233)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:576)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.ibm.isclite.container.collaborator.PortletServletCollaborator.doRender(PortletServletCollaborator.java:71)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.rrd.RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.doRender(RRDServerPortletServletCollaborator.java:123)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.cache.CacheCollaborator.doRender(CacheCollaborator.java:92)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.doCollaborator(PortletServletCollaboratorChainImpl.java:105)
    at com.ibm.ws.portletcontainer.invoker.impl.PortletServlet.doDispatch(PortletServlet.java:273)
    ... 78 more
```

Comment: Posting an SSCCE along with the entire stacktrace may be helpful to learn if the bug is in your or other's code. That "the website cannot display page" error is by the way specific to MSIE browser and not coming from the server side.

Comment: Thank you for the stacktrace. It's very helpful (for ones who can read it; if you're unable to read it please don't blame the stacktrace, but just your own ignorance). It suggests a bug in MyFaces impl. Which MyFaces version are you using? Have you tried the latest? Does your webapp ship with any JSF JARs in its `/WEB-INF/lib` which might cause potential clases in classpath?

Comment: Google shows that you're not the only one with exactly this problem: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=464931 It seems a problem in the specific combination of MyFaces with IBM Portlet. The IBM Portlet API is more likely to blame here (it's not the first time I see "strange" exceptions coming from it). So trying to upgrade the IBM Portlet may be worth the effort.

Comment: Sorry for any miscommunication.   I wanted to be clear that that stack trace made no sense to me.  I'm sure once I use myfaces more I will be better able to understand the stack traces.  I will investigate this further and see if I can't upgrade myfaces implementation.